# VBA Refer to worksheet vs chart sheet

Tags: vba, charts, worksheet, refer

I'm trying to write a small function that takes in a filepath (where the workbook was saved at), targetpath (where the pdf will be saved to), and a string of tab names (pipe (|) delimited) in excel.

The user of the function doesn't have to input a string of tab names (it's optional) and if they don't, I want to select all of the visible tabs and print them. This would be in the case if the user has 50 charts in separate worksheets and don't want to write a string like "Chart1|Chart2|...."

Code:

```
For Each WSO.Name In WBO.Worksheets 
    strSheets = strSheets & WSO.Name & "|" 
Next WSO

strSheets = Left(strSheets, Len(strSheets) - 1) 
arraySheets() = Split(strSheets, "|")

WBO.Sheets(arraySheets()).Select     
WBO.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _ 
    strFilePath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _ 
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _ 
    True
```

There's two problems with the For Each loop: it doesn't grab any sheets such as "Chart1", it only grabs sheets such as "Sheet1". Also, it will grab hidden sheets so that when I try to select them all I get an out of bounds error.

I didn't know if a Chart sheet is referred to differently then a regular sheet or why hidden sheets are also chosen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `WBO.Sheets` instead of `WBO.Worksheets` in the loop.

Verify that `WSO.Visible = xlSheetVisible` to filter out hidden sheets.

Answer (score 7):

> > There's two problems with the For Each loop: it doesn't grab any sheets such as "Chart1", it only grabs sheets such as "Sheet1"

Charts and Worksheets are two different collections.
Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim oCs As Chart

For Each oWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print oWs.Name
Next

For Each oCs In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
    Debug.Print oCs.Name
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course, `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` includes both `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and `ActiveWorkbook.Charts`.